# How to allow an IP in Virtualmin like we did in cpanel for MySQL access?

Tags: linux, mysql, permissions

How can I allow an IP in webmin so I could connect to MySQL with specific user? I could do it in cPanel by adding that IP but in Virtualmin I think it's related to Host permissions or User Permissions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do this in Virtualmin, although access is generally configured on a per-domain basis.

To set it up for existing domains, do the following :

1. Login as the master admin (root), and go to Webmin -> Servers -> MySQL Database, and click on User Permissions.
2. Click on 'Create a new user', and add an user with the username and password for the domain, but with the hosts set to something like 192.168.0.%
3. Go back to the main page of the MySQL module, and click on Database Permissions.
4. Click on 'Create new database permissions', and add a record for the domain's database and user, with all permissions selected, and with the hosts set to 192.168.0.%

If you want all new domains to get acesss from 192.168.0.% by default, go to System Settings -> Server Templates -> Default Settings -> MySQL Database, and fill in the 'Allowed MySQL client hosts' field with 192.168.0.%

I admit that this is a fairly complex process, which is why I plan to add a more user-friendly single-page form for managing MySQL remote hosts to in the next Virtualmin release.

http://www.virtualmin.com/node/7825

Answer (score 0):

I enabled this feature in virtualmin owner limits:

```
Can edit database remote hosts
```

and works fine.